# Implement jquery multiswitch in MVC checkboxfor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor

So I included this jquery form plugin called multiswitch (credits to the [source](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/iOS-like-Smooth-Tri-state-Switch-Plugin-With-jQuery-multiSwitch.html)) in my MVC web project and integrated it using Html.Checkboxfor() in my Create.cshtml and in my model 'IsReserved' bool property. However, it doesn't bind well in my model when I click the submit button and call the Http post of my controller. Refer to screenshots and public repo link below:

https://github.com/ricsierics/Multiswitch-Demo

[image: View code][image: User Interface][image: Model][image: Controller]

Comment: Using that plugin with `CheckBoxFor()` does not make sense since the `CheckBoxFor()` method generates 2 inputs - `<input type="checkbox" .... value="true" />` and `<input type="hidden" .... value="false" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, I can now bind the multiswitch to my model well by adding or removing the 'checked' attribute. See screenshots below. Done also committing changes on the said repo link.

[image: jquery function]

[image: debugging]